# node mailer not working with email templates

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, email-templates

I am trying to send an email using my custom template with pug engine using email templates. Here is my code:

```js
var mailer = require("nodemailer");
const logger = require('./logger');
var path = require('path');
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates');
var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, "../", 'templates', 'resetPassword')
var mailTemplate = new EmailTemplate(templateDir)

// IF i do print templateDir here, it gives me the absolute path 


var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "myuser@gmail.com",
      pass: "mypass"
    }
});
   
exports.sendPasswordReset = async (to, token) => {
 var locals = {
  resetUrl: 'someurlWithToken' + token.toString()
 };

 mailTemplate.render(locals, function(err, temp){ // It throws error with path argument must of type string
  if(err){
   logger.info("ERROR in Render email template" + err)
  } else {
   smtpTransport.sendMail({
    from: "myuser@gmail.com",
    to: to,
    subject: "Password Reset Link",
    text: temp.text,
    html:  temp.html
   }, function(error, response){
    if(error){
     logger.info('Mail Error' + error);
     return console.error(err)
    } else{
     logger.info("Message sent: " + response.message);
     return response;
    }
      });
  }
 })
}
```

I am not sure, what am i missing. The document for the email template shows example without the node mailer transport.